# Sorting a linked-list (mystery segfault)

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, linked-list

I am currently working on sorting a linked list in C as a homework assignment. I'm not looking for a code snippet as an answer, as I understand the value of figuring it out myself. I am receiving a segfault using the function below and I would really appreciate if someone could at least tell me why. The best I could figure out is that it is failing when reaching the following line:

> if ( head->value > head->next->value ) {

EDIT: Changed this line to if (head->next != NULL && head->value > head->next->value){  and am no longer receiving segfaults. However, my output head pointer is giving me the last node in the linked-list. HALP.

I'm not totally sure where to go from here, and even the slightest nudge in the right direction would be very appreciated.

```
struct node *sort_list(struct node *head) {
    bool swapped ;
    struct node * tmp , * orig ;
    orig = head ;

    if ( head == NULL || head->next == NULL ) return head ;
    else {
            do {
                    swapped = false ;
                    if ( head->next != NULL && head->value > head->next->value ) {
                            tmp = head ;
                            head = head->next ;
                            tmp->next = head->next ;
                            head->next = tmp ;

                            swapped = true ;
                    }
                    head = head->next ;
            } while ( swapped == true && head != NULL ) ;
    }
    return orig ;
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem offhand, but if I were you I would make a `swap(...)` function that takes the swapping code and puts it in its own function. Then you can test that function until you're confident it works. Once you have that you can focus on your sorting logic. As it stands, you have to first figure out if it's your sort logic or swap logic that's messing up.

Comment: It would be a worthy investment of your time to learn how to use the debugger. It would obviate the need to ask questions like this (and so many others), and you'd get a lot more done faster.

Comment: Not a matter of learning the debugger, just that I need to get better with it. I have a long road ahead of me!

Comment: While I think the answers you have so far are useful and probably correct, in the future these are best handled by also including the _test cases_ that cause your code to fail. A single-entry list, a double-entry list that doesn't require a swap, a double-entry list that does require a swap, some three-entry lists that are completely reversed, mostly sorted, and already sorted, etc. A handful of these cases can make all the difference in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once head becomes the last element in the linked list, you get your segfault.
I don't want to write the code since it's homework, but add a conditional to check if head->next is null. If it is, you'll want to set head back to the head of the list.

Your bubble sort will need multiple passes through the linked list to sort it. If you initialize your linked list with values 5,4,3,2,1 and print head and print temp and head. You'll probably see  5,4 5,3 5,2 5,1 segfault

Also your sorting formula seems to be a bit off. If you have data such as 2,3,1. You're code would see 2 and 3, swapped would become true and the function would return true.

You may want to use a loop inside to loop so that every iteration of the outer loop will cause 1 pass through the linked list. If there are no swaps after a pass through the entire linked list, then the data is sorted.

```
do{
    for 1 pass through linked list (this can be a for or while loop)
        swap if necessary; set swapped to true
}while(swapped is true)
```

Hope this helps.

Edit

After

```
tmp = head;
```

Add

```
head = head->next  
if(tmp == orig)  
    orig = head;
```

You need to maintain your head pointer.
In the case of 5,4,3,6. It'll sort it as follows
4,5,3,6
4,3,5,6
3,4,5,6
But your orig pointer was never updated, so your output will be truncated to 4,5,6.

Comment: lmk if this fixed the sorting bug. It seems you've got the seg fault fixed.

Comment: I've rewritten my algorithm to this, but I'm still getting improper output. How would you handle hanging onto a pointer to the first node after sorting?

Comment: Check the edits, you need to maintain your orig pointer in your code.

Answer (score 3):

When you enter the `do` loop you know that `head->next` isn't `NULL`, but what about the next time round, or when you reach the final item? The final item doesn't have anything after it.

EDIT:

Suppose you have 3 items in sequence, `A`, `B` and `C`, where `head == B`, and you want to swap items `B` and `C`. You're not taking into account that you also need to do `A->next = C`.

Comment: Edited original. I am receiving improper output still; see OP.

Answer (score 1):

That's caused most likely by a NULL pointer dereference.

You're not checking whether `head->next` is NULL in your loop. After the 1st iteration, `head` becomes `head->next`, and your condition (`if (head->value > head->next->value)`) is dereferencing `head` to access both `value` and `next->value`.

Comment: Edited original. I am receiving improper output still; see OP.

Answer (score 1):

`head->next` is probably null.  You're checking whether it is before the loop, but the `while` condition doesn't perform that check.

And you should find a `gdb` tutorial, it's an incredibly powerful tool for things like this.

Comment: Edited original. I am receiving improper output still; see OP.

Comment: gdb is great, but he might be another semester away from that

Comment: Actually had my first gdb lecture last week. Still pretty new with it though.

Comment: That's great. I didn't use gdb until 2 or 3 years after first seeing a seg fault. I had to rely on print statements and tracing my programs on paper. ... lots of sleepless nights.